# Difference between `do` and `do*` in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, undefined-behavior

I am working on these two functions that differ only in how `ret` and `curr` are assigned their value while the loop runs. In the first function `ret` and `curr` are *bound* in parallel; in the second function they are *bound* sequentially.

parallel *binding*

```
(defun maxpower (base maximum)
    "returns base ^ k such that it is <= maximum"
    (do ((ret 1 curr)               ; parallel
         (curr base (* base curr))) ; binding
        ((> curr maximum) ret)))
```

sequential *binding*

```
(defun maxpower* (base maximum)
    "returns base ^ k such that it is <= maximum"
    (do* ((ret 1 curr)                ; sequential
          (curr base (* base curr)))  ; binding
         ((> curr maximum) ret)))
```

Question: is the 1st function is somehow *wrong* <sup>(*)</sup> because `curr` is both updated and evaluated at the same time (in parallel)?

IOW: if I change the order of the bindings there should be no difference in the parallel version?
How does Lisp decide about the parallelization of the *bindings*?

In my tests, both functions return the same value, as they are.

<sup>(*): I come from C background; I'd say 1st function invokes Undefined Behaviour.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably best to look at `let` versus `let*` first. If you understand that, then `do` versus `do*` follows from that, except for the additional consideration of the step-forms.

Common Lisp is a strictly evaluated language. In both `let` and `let*`, the variable init-forms are evaluated left to right.  The difference is in the scope and binding. Under `let`, all of the *init* forms are evaluated in a scope in which none of the variables are visible, whereas under `let*`, the forms are evaluated in an environment under which all the previous variables are visible.  Secondly, since under `let*`, the previous variables are visible, their values are also established.

Using `let` we can create a scope in which the values of two variables appear swapped:

```
(let ((x y)
      (y x))
   ...)
```

The initializing expressions `y` and `x` are evaluated first, in that order, and then the new values `x` and `y` are bound to the resulting values, which makes this possible.

On the other hand:

```
(let* ((a 1)
       (b (+ a 2)))
```

Here, `1` is evaluated, and `a` is bound. This `a` is then visible to the `(+ a 2)` expression whose value is computed, and bound to `b`.

Now, onto `do`/`do*`. These macros perform, prior to the first iteration, binding of the variables that is exactly like `let`/`let*`. In binding the variables, the difference between `do` and `do*` is exactly like between `let` and `let*`.

The `do`/`do*` macros also have step-forms, which give the next value to their corresponding iteration variables. These step-forms are all in the scope of all of the variables, regardless of whether the macro operator is `do` or `do*`. Whether you're using `do` or `do*`, you can refer to any variable in any step form.  The difference is when the assignment takes place. Under `do`, all of the step forms are evaluated from top to bottom, and then their corresponding variables are assigned new values for the next iteration.  Under `do*`, the behavior is "assign as you go". As each step-form is evaluated, the corresponding variable is assigned. Therefore under `do`, when the step-form refers to any variable, it refers to its value from the prior iteration. Under `do*`, if the step-form refers to a lexically earlier variable, it's picking up the new value. If it refers to a lexically later variable, it's still seeing the old value from the prior iteration.

We have to emphasize that although `let` and `do` have some "parallel" behavior, in a sense, there is no parallel evaluation. All visible effects are performed left to right.  What appears to happen in parallel is the variables coming into existence, or being assigned new values in the new iteration. But this is only parallel in the sense that the program cannot observe the intermediate progress. For instance, the passage of function arguments into a function is likewise "parallel"; the program doesn't observe a state in which the function call is partially in progress, and only half the arguments have been passed.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `maxpower` it is not correct that "*`curr` is both updated and evaluated at the same time*". The step forms in `do` are all evaluated before any assignment takes place. For `do`, the Hyperspec says that "[the assignment of values to vars is done in parallel, as if by `psetq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm)," and for `psetq` it says that ["first all of the forms are evaluated, and only then are the variables set to the resulting values."](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_psetq.htm#psetq)

In the posted code, both definitions should produce the same results because the step forms are evaluated before any assignments are done. But, if the order of the bindings were reversed things would be different:

```
(defun maxpower (base maximum)
  (do ((curr base (* base curr))
       (ret 1 curr))
      ((> curr maximum) ret)))

(defun maxpower* (base maximum)
  (do* ((curr base (* base curr))
        (ret 1 curr))
       ((> curr maximum) ret)))
```

Now for the first function, `(* base curr)` and `curr` are evaluated at the same time, and the values of `curr` and `ret` are updated in parallel. But, for the second function, `(* base curr)` is evaluated and the result assigned to `curr`, and *then* `curr` is evaluated and assigned to `ret`.

For these new definitions you can see that the results differ, where in the original definitions both functions would have returned 4 for both `(maxpower 2 5)` and `(maxpower* 2 5)`:

```
CL-USER> (maxpower 2 5)
4
CL-USER> (maxpower* 2 5)
8
```